# How to Read a value from Excel and include it in the Path

Tags: vba, selenium

I am trying to take a value from excel and include it in the below line using VBA/Selenium:

```
EdgeDr.FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='mls']//td[not(@class='nowrap')and(text()='" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("C2").Value + "']").Click
```

The action should identify the line in a table based on a line mentioned in my Excel spreadsheet

Previous I was identifying the line itself but I needed to make it more flexible:

Previous code:

```
EdgeDr.FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='mls']//td[not(@class='nowrap')and(text()=2)]").Click
```

The part not working is:

```
(text()='" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("C2").Value + "']")
```

Anyone would be able to support ?
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong? There is no error description of your problem. Please also see [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 1):

If this was the original code:

```
EdgeDr.FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='mls']//td[not(@class='nowrap')and(text()=2)]").Click
```

Then this should work:

```
EdgeDr.FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='mls']//td[not(@class='nowrap')and(text()=" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("C2").Value & ")]").Click
```

Note that you introduced extra single quotes `'` and I didn't because there were no before.

Comment: Thanks - yes... Appreciate it - it worked now. Thanks !